# Why div isn't going full height?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

I'm trying to make a sidebar which is the height of the whole page, it is nested within a div called main.

The code is:

```css
.main {
   display: flex;
   overflow-y: hidden;
  }
 
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    background: #212121;
    }

.navbar {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="navbar">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `div` defaults to the size of the unordered list, which is 200px; although I can change it to another size, for example `"height: 500px"`, I do not want to do that, because of different screen sizes.

Is there any way to do this without using viewpoint sizes, something like `height: 100%`, but that actually works?

Comment: you need to position the sidebar -- https://jsfiddle.net/mo1jarf1/

Comment: I would do that, but then the main div ignores the size of it..

Comment: what size? do a full demo on jsfiddle to demonstrate what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want your `.main` to be the full height (and width) of the window, you can position that absolutely and stretch it.

```
 .main {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Depends what you are looking for in regard to the .main div.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help